# How to pass values left join query values to blade template in Laravel app

Tags: laravel

Please see and code and identify the issue.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
   {
   $students = DB::table('students_personal_info_tbl')
   ->leftJoin('students_class_info_tbl', 'students_personal_info_tbl.id', '=', 
     'students_class_info_tbl.student_id')
   ->get();
    
   return view('students.index',['students' => $students])
      ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
       // unable to pass students to blade view        
   }
```

**Blade View**

```
@extends('students.layout')
@section('content')


<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-responsive align-middle">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:30px">#</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th style="width:86px">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($students as $student)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->fullName }}</td>
     
        <td class="actionsControls">
            <form action="{{ route('students.destroy',$student->id) }}" method="POST">

                <a href="{{ route('students.show',$student->id) }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>
                <a href="{{ route('students.edit',$student->id) }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-edit"></i></a>
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <a  href="{{ route('students.destroy',$student->id) }}" type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tobdy>
</table>


    <!-- $students->links() -->


@endsection
```

**Note:** if I echo `$students` in controller, not in blade template/view it is working and printing the values. But I want to pass values and print in blade view.

**Error Details:**
[image]

Comment: Please post the code for the blade view

Comment: It seems you use delete route without student id. Check your view and if you have delete route pass the student id. `route('students.destroy', [$student->id])`

Comment: Donkarnash blade view added in snippet.

Comment: xuma code updated as per your suggestion, but still app is showing same error

Comment: You need to use array  not directly use variable. Look  at my answer.

Comment: @xuma 2nd parameter to the `route()` is of type **mixed** so passing `$student->id` also works, for more clarity it could be written as `route('students.destroy', ['student' => $student->id])`. However it should work with just `$student->id`. @dev Are you still getting **Missing required parameter for route** error?

Comment: Try replacing `<a  href="{{ route('students.destroy',$student->id) }}" type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a>` with a `<button   type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>`

Comment: @dev Also try `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan route:clear` then refresh the page and check. Can you check the route declaration for students.destroy route to ensure it has just one param - {student}